# GCP - Not able to Push docker image from Compute Engine to Container Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm not able to push docker images from Compute Engine VM to Container registry. I have added the credentials to the service account but I still get:

unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service account should have roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter role on GCR's bucket (artifacts.PROJECT-ID.appspot.com for gcr.io). More documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control).